# DevTools failed to load SourceMap for webpack:///node_modules//....js.map HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools

I created a simple webpack based project to learn snabbdom. Everything was OK except that sourcemap failed loading:

[image]

I don't know whose issue(webpack, chrome) it is. Is there anyone who know it?

Reproduction steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/tomwang1013/snabbdom-test.git
npm install
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 71):

The source map you are trying to load is in `node_modules` and not part of webpack bundle. "If not extracted and processed into the source map of the webpack bundle, browsers may misinterpret source map data" [ref](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader). When app is loaded that causes "ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" in chrome dev tools console.

To process `node_module` source maps to webpack bundle, use `source-map-loader` loader. That will fix console warnings.

Add dependency to `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "source-map-loader": "^1.0.0",
    ...
}
```

Update `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      use: ['source-map-loader'],
    },
  ],
},
```

To generate source maps for [snabbdom-test](https://github.com/tomwang1013/snabbdom-test.git) project in general you can use `SourceMapDevToolPlugin`.

Update `webpack.config.js`:

```
const { SourceMapDevToolPlugin } = require("webpack");

plugins: [
  new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    filename: "[file].map"
  }),
...
],
```

Comment: Hi, @Rokas Lengvenis. I'm having the same message at my console in a project with TypeScript. Just to certify I'll do correctly: Do I have to install `source-map-loader` with any package manager (like npm, yarn, etc.)? Or do I have to enter in `package.json` and in `webpack.config.js` and type it manually? Regards.

Comment: @jose-renato-m, you can install it directly with `yarn add source-map-loader` or `npm install`. Then add this loader manually to `webpack.config.js` file as that will allow to use source-map 'extracting' from `node_modules` while making a bundle.

Comment: That helped me fixing at least 1 of the two dev tool errors I have. Thanks a lot. The other one is a chromium bug I [heard](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/10469) they'll fix that in the next browser patch, so yah.. annoying but at least it doesn't have to do anything with my own code.

Comment: FYI, I used https://stackoverflow.com/q/64842607 with webpack 5.

Comment: Thank you, I used the updated version with my project and it actually removed a few other violations that occured. Thank you again!

Answer (score 46):

Update `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    entry: {
      "app": "src/app.js"
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: "[name].js",
      sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map"
    },
    devtool: "source-map"
    // ...
};
```

Detailed in https://blog.sentry.io/2018/10/18/4-reasons-why-your-source-maps-are-broken

Comment: This just includes the source content in the source map it does not allow the browser to fetch the source itself as the value in the `sources` array will still start with `webpack://`.

Comment: This was the best answer for me. Solved it straight away

Answer (score 29):

```
  devtool: "eval-cheap-source-map"
```

Add this to your webpack config and that's it.

Comment: See the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) for details on this and other `devtool` settings.

Answer (score 18):

Add `devtool: 'eval-source-map'` to top most level of webpack.config

Comment: See the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) for details on this and other `devtool` settings.

Comment: Easiest solution for modern Webpack

Comment: This got rid of the warnings in Chrome devtools console. I was using `'eval'` but I guess that didn't satisfy Chrome but `'eval-source-map'` did the trick. This is what I did inside the function exported for a webpack v5 config: `const isProduction = argv.mode === 'development' ? false : true;`   `devtool: isProduction ? undefined : 'eval-source-map',`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just turn these off, you can use a webpack `devtool` option that ignores them. Detailed in [my related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63022130/webpack-make-it-ignore-source-files-that-cant-be-found)

Answer (score 3):

Add below line to your weback config

```
  devtool: 'source-map ./src',
```

Comment: See the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) for details on this and other `devtool` settings.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing helps, try to use different [webpack devtool mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/).

Related the project for me working good this modes:

```
devtool: 'inline-source-map'
```

or

```
devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map'
```

or

```
devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map'
```

or

```
devtool: 'inline-cheap-module-source-map'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're here and you're using Typescript, make sure you've got `sourceMap: true` in compilerOptions in your tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

@Phương Nam's answer will solve this error but even after setting `filename: "[name].js"`, webpack may warn us regarding the conflict of multiple assets emitting to the same filename.

To fix above warning we can use `SourceMapDevToolPlugin`.

> This plugin enables more fine grained control of source map
> generation. It is also enabled automatically by certain settings of
> the devtool configuration option.

The following code to replace the configuration option `devtool: inline-source-map` with an equivalent custom plugin configuration:

```
    // ...
    plugins: [
        // ...
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({})
        // ...
    ],
    devtool: false
    // ...
```

More examples of [SourceMapDevToolPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/#examples)

Answer (score 0):

I am using webpack to build and get that same browser error if I build in development mode.

For example in my package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx webpack --mode development",
    "prod": "npx webpack --mode production"
  }
```

However, if I build with *production* mode instead of *development* mode that error goes away, most likely for reasons mentioned in above answers.

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps in each of those js files  there is something like url commented:
`/*# sourceMappingURL=dsggdgdg.fdgdfn.dfg.map */`

remove that

Comment: That's autogenerated lines, even if you remove them, they will be regenerated once you recompile project, so no use.

Comment: @AidOnline01 what recompiling . I use ready to use js libs. Removed those strings once. Putting the libs into a separate public folder. How to recompile ? Wasnt js a native language for browsers, or did you talk  about some higher level script languages?