# Webpack: make it ignore source files that can't be found?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using snabbdom.js and webpack to build a JS front-end app. I have a very simple snabbdom view and webpack config that bundles it up. When I load the bundle in chrome I get all this stuff in the console:

[image: webpack source map warnings]

I can set the webpack `mode` to `production` which does get rid of these warnings but it also turns off *all* source maps, so that's not really helpful. I found this other related question that [describes how to use a plugin to load them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61767538/devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-for-webpack-node-modules-js-map-http-e). But I don't want to mess around with configuring a plugin for source maps I don't actually want. Is there a way to tell webpack to just ignore these?

Answer (score 12):

I read up a bit more on the details of each option in [the webpack `devtools` options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) and found that adding
`devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',` to my webpack config did the trick.

From the docs:

> it doesn't have column mappings, it only maps line numbers. It ignores SourceMaps from Loaders and only display transpiled code similar to the eval devtool

Comment: Thank-you, I had been ignoring hundreds of warnings about "failed to load sourcemap" for far too long -- now they are finally gone.