# How to correctly expose jQuery with Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-5

Is there any specific way to expose jQuery with Webpack 5?

It used to work on Webpack 4 OK, with the config bellow, but it shows the `Uncaught Reference Error: jQuery is not defined` error now with 5.

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: {
          exposes: ['$', 'jQuery'],
        },
      },
```

Comment: Do you load `jquery` with `script` element in html?

Comment: Nope I import it in bundle.js, as so: import $ from 'jquery';

Then I add bundle tot he html.

Comment: Then why not just use that imported `$`? I'm not sure about your use case here. Would be great if you can clarify it.

Comment: Amazingly, this worked for me for webpack 5. Thank you!

Comment: Had the same issue after upgrading to 5. Only the inline syntax worked `import videojs from 'expose-loader?exposes=videojs!video.js';`

Answer (score 1):

Confirming @Sam Chen 's comment above, Webpack 5 (as of 5.75) does not require expose-loader to make `$` available as an import. It was simplest to uninstall the loader, remove it from webpack.config.js, and add

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
```

to all files that used it. This can get messy in the case of TypeScript projects with @types/jquery, as pages where the import is missing may not warn about it.