# Could not load content for webpack://react-devtools-extensions/react-devtools-shared/src/backend/console.js and console logs appear from index.js:103

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am woking on a Next.js project using the pages router. In the browser console, all console.logs are coming from a file called "index.js", but when I inspect the file, the logs come from the line `original.apply(this, args);` in a from a line that contains:

```js
function replace(_logger, level) {
        if (!_logger[level]) {
            return () => {
            };
        }
        return patch(_logger, level, (original) => {
            return (...args) => {
                original.apply(this, args);
                if (inStack) {
                    return;
                }
                inStack
```

For refrence, this file begins with

```js
import { patch } from '../../../utils.js';
import { ErrorStackParser } from './error-stack-parser.js';
import { stringify } from './stringify.js';

const defaultLogOptions = {
    level: [
        'assert',
        'clear',
        'count',
        'countReset',
        'debug',
        'dir',
        'dirxml',
        'error',
        'group',
        'groupCollapsed',
        'groupEnd',
        'info',
        'log',
        'table',
        'time',
        'timeEnd',
        'timeLog',
        'trace',
        'warn',
    ],
    lengthThreshold: 1000,
    logger: 'console',
};
function initLogObserver(cb, win, options) {
```

and has not been touched by me, nor have I seen it before.
My depenencies are listed below:

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.7.14",
        "@notionhq/client": "^2.2.3",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
        "@types/node": "18.14.2",
        "@types/react": "18.0.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
        "cookie": "^0.5.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.2.1",
        "graphql": "^16.6.0",
        "knex": "^2.4.2",
        "next": "13.2.1",
        "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
        "next-connect": "^1.0.0",
        "next-router-mock": "^0.9.3",
        "next-test-api-route-handler": "^3.1.8",
        "objection": "^3.0.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-dropdown": "^1.11.0",
        "react-pdf": "^7.0.3",
        "react-select": "^5.7.3",
        "react-text-transition": "^3.0.2",
        "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
        "remark-html": "^15.0.2",
        "sharp": "^0.32.3",
        "sqlite3": "^5.1.6",
        "typescript": "4.9.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "source-map-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "eslint": "^8.41.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-n": "^16.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
        "jest": "^29.5.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
        "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
        "next-connect": "^1.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.21",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
    }
```

I tried fixing the source maps using [eval-cheap-source-map in the webpack devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209788/13203692), but the logging was still all from like 103 in the same file.

Additionally, if I inspect the source in the chrome devtools, there is a file called "console.log" that contains:
`Could not load content for webpack://react-devtools-extensions/react-devtools-shared/src/backend/console.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)`

Any and all advice relating to solutions, or just on how to approach debugging would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same issue : xCould not load content for webpack://react-devtools-extensions/react-devtools-shared/src/backend/console.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Took it as a sign it was time to move to appDir. please lmk if you do though. Good luck!